# Identify Strategy Game with Chariots and Elephants

Tags: identify-this-game

This was a strategy board game I played a few times as a child almost 20 years ago. Here is what I remember:

1. There were two sides with identical sets of pieces. I seem to recall the sides being brown and grey.
2. There were medieval soldier pieces. Some chariots (that the soldiers could ride), and elephants.
3. Each player has a set number of moves per turn that he can distribute as he sees fit on his pieces.
4. There was a hierarchy of power. I'm pretty sure a soldier (alone) couldn't kill an elephant.
5. The map was a network of connected circles.
6. Each side had a castle composed of 5 or 6 connected circles.
7. To win you had to occupy your opponents castle.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted - seems like a reasonable and objectively answerable question!  Also, sounds like an interesting game...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The game you are looking for is [Conquest](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/20467/conquest):

[image]

Comment: Ooh, pretty board...

Comment: Yes! That's it! A self published game? Hmmm. Makes me really wonder where the people who had it got it from. It's not like we have a big board game market in Asia.

Comment: Awesome ... it looks interesting enough that I might even check it out.

Comment: I added a link to the BGG page.  There are multiple different versions with different BGG pages, so I chose the earliest one, but that might not be the version that you had.