# What is the board game featured in this Houkago Saikoro Kurabu picture?

Tags: identify-this-game

Can someone identify the game in this picture? It comes from the manga Houkago Saikoro Kurabu, which has a history of [showcasing real board games](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%94%BE%E8%AA%B2%E5%BE%8C%E3%81%95%E3%81%84%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D%E5%80%B6%E6%A5%BD%E9%83%A8#.E4.BD.9C.E4.B8.AD.E3.81.AB.E5.87.BA.E3.81.A6.E3.81.8F.E3.82.8B.E3.82.B2.E3.83.BC.E3.83.A0) (particularly eurogames) so it is very likely not just made up for the manga:

[image: picture]

Here's a higher-resolution image of the board itself, which shows better details on the pieces and the map:

[image: board zoom-in]

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that the board game actually exists and was not made up for the manga?

Comment: @jwodder
Yes, I do. I've seen images from same manga featuring Marrakesh, Catan, Spot It, Carcassonne and some other real existing board games. http://gekkansunday.net/wp-content/uploads/%E6%94%BE%E8%AA%B2%E5%BE%8C%E3%81%95%E3%81%84%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D%E5%80%B6%E6%A5%BD%E9%83%A8/saikoro_01.jpg
http://gekkansunday.net/wp-content/uploads/%E6%94%BE%E8%AA%B2%E5%BE%8C%E3%81%95%E3%81%84%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D%E5%80%B6%E6%A5%BD%E9%83%A8/saikoro_02.jpg

Comment: [The wikipedia page for the series](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%94%BE%E8%AA%B2%E5%BE%8C%E3%81%95%E3%81%84%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D%E5%80%B6%E6%A5%BD%E9%83%A8#.E4.BD.9C.E4.B8.AD.E3.81.AB.E5.87.BA.E3.81.A6.E3.81.8F.E3.82.8B.E3.82.B2.E3.83.BC.E3.83.A0) (japanese) has a list of featured games for each chapter of the manga up to volume 8 (not having read the manga, no clue how complete it is) but this doesn't appear to be any of them. Do you know if this image comes from any particular chapter/volume, or is it just a standalone promotional image?

Comment: @goldPseudo No, I have no idea what chapter this image comes from. Thanks for wikipedia link, even if it's not helpful it's definitely interesting

Comment: Found this thread on BGG. https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1067202/after-school-dice-club-new-manga-about-board-games

Comment: Looks a lot like a simplified version of pandemic:P  Only 2 plague colours...perhaps because the other 2 are eradicated?  Maybe I am being swayed by games I own=}

Comment: @joedragons I would agree that it looks close enough, but authors are pretty consistent in accuratly describing other games down to smallest details. They also displayed rather well known games so far, so I hoped one woudn't be so hard to identify...

Comment: Honey’s Anime confirms that this manga contains good game research. https://honeysanime.com/top-10-board-tabletop-game-manga-best-recommendations/

Comment: Looks like the author’s twitter account shows the games he plays.  https://mobile.twitter.com/shimaneko555

Comment: The board looks like the image in this answer: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/4385

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The author has confirmed on Twitter that it is an imaginary game:

> [image: こんにちは！ありがとうございます。そのイラストのゲームは僕の想像のゲームで実在しないんですよ〜（＾ω＾）]

Translation courtesy Google Translate:

> Hello! Thank you very much. The game with that illustration is my imaginary game and doesn't really exist ~ (^ ω ^)

Comment: Thats a disappointing answer!  I've been showing this picture to friends and googling descriptions of the pawns convinced I recognised it.   Thanks for finding there is no answer though.